# Errors running Oolong validation in R on both STM and seededLDA

Tags: r, topicmodels

I'm trying to run the oolong package to validate a couple of topic models I've created. Using both an STM model and a seededLDA model (this code won't be reproducible)

```
oolong_test1a <- witi(input_model = model_stm_byt, input_corpus = YS$body)
```

OR

```
oolong_test1a <- witi(input_model = slda_howard_docs, input_corpus = howard_df$content)
```

In both cases it successfully creates an oolong test in my global environment. However, when I run either the word intrusion or topic intrusion test, I get this error in both my console and my viewer:

```
 Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7122
Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'miniUI-0.1.1.1'; `directoryPath` = 'D:/temp/RtmpAh8J5r/RLIBS_35b54642a1c09/miniUI/www'
  [No stack trace available]
```

I couldn't find any reference to this error anywhere else. I've checked I'm running the most recent version of oolong.

I've also tried to run it on the models/corpus that comes supplied with oolong. So this code is reproducible:

```
oolong_test <- witi(input_model = abstracts_keyatm, input_corpus = abstracts$text, userid = "Julia")
oolong_test$do_word_intrusion_test()
oolong_test$do_topic_intrusion_test()
```

This generates the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version in github that fixes this issue.

```
devtools::install_github("chainsawriot/oolong")
```